# How to know when a dart polymer element gets rendered completely

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have created a polymer element that draws a data table from a data source url. The code is at https://github.com/dennisfrancis/polymer-dart-datatable-example

My aim is to measure the time taken by the polymer element to render itself completely once the new data is available in the client. I tried the following but with no success.

```dart
/**
 * A Polymer datatable element.
 */
@CustomTag('dennis-datatable')
class DataTable extends PolymerElement {

  ....
  ....
  @observable int numrows = 0;
  @observable int numcols = 0;
  @observable List<String> cols;
  @observable List<Map<String,dynamic>> rows;

  .....
  .....      
  DateTime start_render;
  DateTime stop_render;

  DataTable.created() : super.created() {
    ....
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("load", prn_latency);
    fetch_data();
    ....
  }

  void fetch_data([Timer _]) {

    ....
    .....
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR

    // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
    request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) {
      if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
          (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)) {

        update_data(request.responseText);

      }

    });

    request.open(method, dataSrc);

    if(method == "POST") {
      request.send(jsonArgs); // perform the async POST
    } else {
      request.send();
    }

  }

  void prn_latency(Event e) {
    if (start_render == null) { return; }
    stop_render = new DateTime.now();
    int diff = stop_render.millisecondsSinceEpoch - start_render.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("render time = $diff ms");
  }

  void update_data(String jsonString) {

    Map data = JSON.decode(jsonString);
    numrows = data["numrows"];
    numcols = data["numcols"];
    cols    = data["cols"];
    rows    = data["rows"];

    this.start_render = new DateTime.now();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `attached()` after the `super()` call is the best place.

```dart
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    // stop_render
  }
```

If you want put `start_render` into the element too `polymerCreated()` before the `super()` call should be the best place.

```dart
  void polymerCreated() {
    // start_render
    super.polymerCreated()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Günter, I tried adding these but it looks like enteredView() is getting called only once, even before fetch_data() is getting called. The method enteredView() does not get called when data changes. Is there a function that gets called when the polymer element sub-tree changes (due to data changes)?

Comment: Sorry I missed that requirement. I don't know a callback for updates after the initial rendering. In this case `MutationObservers` may help but it may influence the measuring.

Comment: I tried using MutationObservers to calculate the time but it gave me result of more than 10 times the time it took for another raw dart program(without polymer : [github-link](https://github.com/dennisfrancis/table-rendering-benchmark) ) to generate the table with the **same** data

Comment: Can you please post your benchmark results on https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!forum/web

Comment: My post at https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/web/Y9-gNVl43fs

Comment: I have started a new [branch](https://github.com/dennisfrancis/polymer-dart-datatable-example/tree/min_templates) that moved the table generation logic out of the template to a private dart method of the class inherited from PolymerElement class. Now the rendering speeds are competitive to that of the raw dart program.